# Create prototype property

Tags: typescript

As far as i know, typescript does not differentiate between prototype properties and instance properties. Also, there is no detection for `Object.defineProperty` on the prototype, similar to [a feature for typechecking js](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#objectdefineproperty-declarations-in-javascript).

As such, is the "normal" way to make a prototype property to simply declare it, and define it outside the class, without TS being able to confirm this?

```
class C {
  declare readonly x: string;
}
Object.defineProperty(
  C.prototype,
  'x',
  { value: 'something' },
);
```

In the specific case, i am extending `Error`, and want to override `Error.prototype.name`. This seems to be best done by in turn adding a prototype property on the subclass.

Comment: Since [ES `class` syntax doesn't support non-method prototype properties](//stackoverflow.com/q/38311805/2887218) then there's no "clean" way to do this that I know of.  There's nothing particularly wrong with your approach; there are many times where TS can't verify something, and this is just one of those times.  I don't know if I can say whether or not it's "normal", it would be conjecture on my part since it's rare to do such things.  I'm not really sure why you don't just use an instance property, although presumably that's out of scope for the question.

Comment: Thanks, i suspected as much, but am sometimes surprised by something i didn't know, hence rather ask anyways. I could use an instance property (it even was, i just re-visited it, because i switched to `noImplicitOverride`). It overrides `Error.prototype.name`, a prototype property, and is kind of one-for-all, and readonly. All it does is replace the default name "Error" with the subclass' name. However, as performance is more or less irrelevant here, and no-one cares about the few bytes extra for each instance, i guess it's more of a theoretical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "normal" way is simply to use instance properties instead of prototype properties; or, put another way, there is no "normal" way to use prototype properties because they aren't very well supported and don't lead to idiomatic Typescript.

```
class A {
    // instance property instead of prototype property
    readonly x: string = 'foo';
}
```

If you are particularly concerned about memory use - perhaps you are going to have millions of instances of `A` and you don't want them all to hold individual references to the same constant - then you can declare a property accessor using the `get` keyword. This accessor belongs to the class, not the instances:

```
class B {
    // behaves like a readonly property, but belongs to the prototype
    get x(): string {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
// "foo"
console.log(new B().x);
// false
console.log(new B().hasOwnProperty('x'));
// true
console.log(B.prototype.hasOwnProperty('x'));
```

If you are also concerned about the theoretical minuscule performance cost of an accessor method compared to a simple property (this should be inlined by the JIT, but...), then the only reason Typescript won't allow you to assign `C.prototype.x = ...;` directly is because you declared it as `readonly`. That is, if Typescript is going to check the type of `C.prototype.x` then it's also going to check that this property is writable. So you can get type-checking if you don't make `x` readonly:

```
class C {
    // not readonly, allowing direct assignment to the prototype
    declare x: string;
}
// OK
C.prototype.x = 'foo';
// Error
C.prototype.x = { value: 'bar' };
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQPTugSwHYQBcxdgBTaABwCcB7C0qggTx3wNLABNoaAzS2gRrN6Aug2Yo0VDpxq4QLAB4AuaISp4A5tAC80AOS8aNAwG4kAXyRJQkGACFEU1JmgAjUgAswAN1IwINgA1uRg0DJc8opi9IxMADQeAK4EHqQg8lowQtAEXuTUwsJM9C7QWqRpSgAUAJRqGtrOaK0RVclUuIbGphat1tZuAES9w7byEDQgpAB0mVo1uKQA7tAO9bNKdRZuvGAgEKQT+NNzC0ur65s+EADyK7gACrRxzDUGSgZ1O0huBFRksdgJMzvMaIsHLMikIRHNbg9nq8JEwPl8fhZbOAoNAAMItNBuXDCdpRBSJaAHTIrZqcbAyYBpezYLS4AC2pFwaVy+UKghKZVanFIdhk0FU6gB2gsQywdwA0khcdD+XCtnoeiZzH8sABRKi0KhKlXFNVKDUIaC+A5AtQGdxgKgGaCWCxAA)

Comment: Thanks, the idea with the `get` is interesting, i hadn't thought of it. As you and others suggest, i'll probably switch from a prototype property to an instance property. While not perfectly proper, as you mention, it just doesn't matter in most cases.